# How do I format a Javascript date like 1950-12-30T18:25:43.511Z

Tags: javascript, date, format, timestamp, date-format

I have an API where I the date need to be formatted like this

```
1950-12-30T18:25:43.511Z
```

This format looks somewhat unfamiliar to me, and I'm wondering how I can take a format like this

```
1950-12-30
```

and turn it into something like the former. FYI I'm using javascript (express)

Comment: What does it mean? March 28th, 977?

Comment: [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) is a good starting point. Also `.setYear()`, `.setMonth()`, and `.setDate()`

Comment: @GolezTrol the dates themselves are not important, just the format, I just put them in for illustration

Comment: Of course the dates are important. You want to convert '0977-03-28' to '1950-12-30T18:25:43.511Z'. The first one hardly looks like a date to me. Without proper interpretation, there is no good conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to put the date into ISO format and the native `Date` object will do that for you, fairly simply, with the `.toISOString()` method:

```
var newDate = new Date("0977-03-28");
console.log(newDate.toISOString());
```

The result of that is: `0977-03-28T00:00:00.000Z` (look familiar?   :D   )

One issue that you will have (if it is an issue), is that, because you only have the date value, and not a time value, the last part of the string will always be `T00:00:00.000Z` (which is the "time" section of the `Date`).  You'll see that if you use today's date, using `var newDate = new Date();` (which captures this instant), the time will be filled in:  `2015-02-19T16:50:18.078Z` (at the time of testing)

For more information, see here:   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

(**Note:** in IE, this only works in v9 or later, though, that link also has a polyfill for older IE versions)